# Showing File Upload progress with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net

I',m trying to figure out how to do a multipart/form-data put request and be able to get upload the progress of my file. The problem I am having is that the request is not sent until request.GetResponse(); making my writing progress go to 100% before sending. I have tried googling and found people solving it by using request.SendChunked = true; and request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false; but this does not seem to do any difference. I have seen several people post about this but not found a solution that I get working, yet. This is my attempt. Any idea what I can do to solve this?

```
class Program
{
    private static float _progressBar;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
        // https://postman-echo.com/put
        var response =  ExecutePutCommand("C:/temp/zipfile.zip",
            "https://postman-echo.com/put", "weef");
     }

    protected static string ExecutePutCommand(string filename, string uriStr, string stringToAdd)
    {
        try
        {
            const string authCookie = "";
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            //
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uriStr);
            request.SendChunked = true;
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

            string boundary = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            //
            request.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data;boundary={0}", boundary);
            request.Method = "PUT";
            //request.Headers["Cookie"] = authCookie;

            // Build Contents for Post
            string header = string.Format("--{0}", boundary);
            string footer = header + "--";
            // string builders are for the text above and below the file - file is kept in its original format.
            StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder contents2 = new StringBuilder();

            // Zip File
            contents.AppendLine(header);
            contents.AppendLine(
                string.Format("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"filefield\"; filename=\"{0}\"",
                    filename));
            contents.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed");
            contents.AppendLine();

            // file goes here... then contents 2

            contents2.AppendLine();
            // Form Field 1
            contents2.AppendLine(header);
            contents2.AppendLine("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"stringToAdd\"");
            contents2.AppendLine();
            contents2.AppendLine(stringToAdd);
            // Form Field 2
            // Footer
            contents2.AppendLine(footer);

            // This is sent to the Put
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents.ToString());
            byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents2.ToString());
            byte[] formData = bytes.Concat(fileBytes).Concat(bytes2).ToArray();
           
            // calculate size of the stream
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length + fileBytes.Length + bytes2.Length;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int count = 0;
            int length = 0;
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            //request.Proxy = null;
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (Stream inputStream = new MemoryStream(formData))
                {

                    while ((count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                        length += count;

                        _progressBar = (float)length / request.ContentLength;
                        //Console.WriteLine(_progressBar);
                    }
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
           
            WebResponse resp =  request.GetResponse();
            Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            using (Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader respReader = new StreamReader(stream);
                sw2.Stop();
                return respReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return String.Empty;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

If i do a curl from the command line it will start a tickingupload progress text that shows how many mb has been uploaded and expected time left so the postman server seems to support this functionality:

C:\temp>curl -v -X PUT -F "filefield=@C:\temp\zipfile.zip" -F "field2=blah" https://postman-echo.com/put > log.txt
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 107.23.124.180...

- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to postman-echo.com (107.23.124.180) port 443 (#0)
- schannel: SSL/TLS connection with postman-echo.com port 443 (step 1/3)
- schannel: checking server certificate revocation
- schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 181 bytes...
- schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 181 bytes
- schannel: SSL/TLS connection with postman-echo.com port 443 (step 2/3)
- schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
- schannel: SSL/TLS connection with postman-echo.com port 443 (step 2/3)
- schannel: encrypted data got 4096
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4096 length 4096
- schannel: encrypted data length: 4030
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4030 length 4096
- schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
- schannel: SSL/TLS connection with postman-echo.com port 443 (step 2/3)
- schannel: encrypted data got 1024
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 5054 length 5054
- schannel: encrypted data length: 200
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 200 length 5054
- schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
- schannel: SSL/TLS connection with postman-echo.com port 443 (step 2/3)
- schannel: encrypted data got 147
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 347 length 5054
- schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 126 bytes...
- schannel: SSL/TLS connection with postman-echo.com port 443 (step 2/3)
- schannel: encrypted data got 258
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 258 length 5054
- schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
- schannel: SSL/TLS connection with postman-echo.com port 443 (step 3/3)
- schannel: stored credential handle in session cache

> PUT /put HTTP/1.1
> Host: postman-echo.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 11472946
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------3afff00f52d07df7

- schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
- schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
- schannel: encrypted data got 54
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 54 length 103424
- schannel: decrypted data length: 25
- schannel: decrypted data added: 25
- schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 25 length 102400
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
- schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 25 length 102400
- schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
- schannel: decrypted data returned 25
- schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
  < HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
  } [160 bytes data]

**31 10.9M    0     0   31 3552k      0   208k  0:00:53  0:00:17  0:00:36  317k**

Comment: Http has stream mode (1.0) and chunk mode (1.1). When a connection is made a negotiation is done between client and server to get a common mode of transfer.  Chunk mode will only work if server supports chunk mode.  Try adding to your request the following : request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but sadly, that made no difference. I updated my code to show how i use your suggestion. 

If i do a curl from the command line I can get a progress meter so it seems like postman echo server supports this. 

C:\temp> curl -X PUT -F "filefield=@C:\temp\zipfile.zip" -F "field2=blah" https://postman-echo.com/put > log.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  8 10.9M    0     0    8  944k      0   236k  0:00:47  0:00:04  0:00:43  218k^C